# Google Cloud Platform: Kubernetes Engine add a Region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So,

I have a kubernetes engine cluster with just a single zone/region.. now I want to add more regions to the cluster, so that if someone from a different part of the world access my app can have a better experience.
How is this possible?

Do I just to add another cluster with the different region configured or how would that work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between zone and region. For a better user experience a regional cluster is not going to be helpful, as it is going to create the cluster in 3 differnet zones of the same region. This resolves high availability issues, rather then user experience.

If you want your cluster to be available worldwide, you would need to create separate clusters, in different zones. Note that you can make them regional, to ensure high availability, but then it needs to be X regional clusters, which will end up creating 3·X clusters. That's an expensive pleasure.

Now, say you have 3 clusters in 3 different zones (1 in the US, 1 in Europe, and 1 in Asia). You can manage them as 3 separate clusters, or as one, through [Federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/).

Federation is an advanced topic though. For now you should go for managing the clusters manually.

Best.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your helpful answer. sounds good. Could I also just deploy several clusters and apply them to different regions and then use the google cloud load balancer to load balance across those different clusters? or is this not possible?

Comment: with native GCP resources, you can't do that, as you can't configure several backends for the load balancer.